# NDK and OpenGL ES extensions

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I've never used opengl extensions before, so I'm a little confused. I want to use the extension `EXT_disjoint_timer_query` defined in this [file (gl2ext.h)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/GLES2/gl2ext.h). Then, I saw that I need to use NDK and the `eglGetProcAddress` to do that, but the file gl2ext.h that comes with the NDK it's different from the khrono's website (that contains the extension that I want). Is it ok just to add the khrono's gl2ext.h file manually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the newer gl2ext.h from Khronos. It should be a superset of the older version in the NDK.